# Spring animation is not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-spring

The below Spring animation is not working in ReactJS.

I have a Component class written like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from 'react'
import { Spring } from 'react-spring'

export default class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { isMouseOver: false };
        this.handleMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this);
    }

    handleMouseEnter(e) {
        this.setState({ isMouseOver: true });
    }

    handleMouseLeave() {
        this.setState({ isMouseOver: false });
    }

    LogoText(props) {
        const isMouseOver = props.isMouseOver;
        const handleMouseEnter = props.handleMouseEnter;
        const handleMouseLeave = props.handleMouseLeave;

        if (isMouseOver) {
            return (
                <Spring
                    from={{ opacity: 0 }}
                    to={{ opacity: 1 }}
                >
                    {
                        (props) => (
                            <div style={props}>
                                hover<!--this renders fine-->
                                <div className='upperDivLogoText' onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}>
                                    <span><a href='#' style={{ color: '#d8f3dc' }} >dWare.sk</a></span>
                                    <a href='#' style={{ color: '#95d5b2' }}>dWare.sk</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                </Spring>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div className='upperDivLogoText' onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}>
                    <span><a href='#' style={{ color: '#d8f3dc' }} >dWare.sk</a></span>
                    <a href='#' style={{ color: '#95d5b2' }}>dWare.sk</a>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='upperDiv'>
                <this.LogoText
                    isMouseOver={this.state.isMouseOver}
                    handleMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
                    handleMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
                />
                <div className='lowerDiv'>
                    <ul className='lowerDivMenu'>
                        <li><a href='#'>O MNE</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>MOJE PORTFÓLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>KONTAKT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But if I hover over upperDivLogoText it just doesn't do anything. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

SOLUTION:
It is because of Spring version 9. For anyone having such a problem just uninstall latest spring and do npm i react-spring@8.0.20

Comment: Thanks for the lead but do you think that it is because of that ?

Comment: I did. I created a new Component LogoText and unfortunately it just behaves the same. Also I did `{console.log(props.opacity)}` inside the arrow function and here is the output:`SpringValue {id: 1, key: "opacity", _priority: 0, _children: Set(0), animation: Animation, …}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As on March-2021, and as mentioned in [comments under this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66800192/2873538), [react-spring V9](https://www.react-spring.io/log) isn't yet released and may have breaking changed. Hence, It would be **safe** to use V8.

But, in V9, the animation is working using `useSpring` hook and `animated.div`:

**Example:**

```
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring' // Using hooks in V9

function LogoText({ isMouseOver, handleMouseEnter, handleMouseLeave }) {

  const style = useSpring({
    opacity: isMouseOver ? 1 : 0,
    from: { opacity: 0 },
  })

  if (!isMouseOver) {
    return (
      <div
        className="upperDivLogoText" onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      >
        <span>
          <a href="#" style={{ color: '#d8f3dc' }}>
            dWare.sk
          </a>
        </span>
        <a href="#" style={{ color: '#95d5b2' }}>
          dWare.sk
        </a>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <animated.div style={style}>
      <div
        className="upperDivLogoText" onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      >
        <span>
          <a href="#" style={{ color: '#d8f3dc' }}>
            dWare.sk
          </a>
        </span>
        <a href="#" style={{ color: '#95d5b2' }}>
          dWare.sk
        </a>
      </div>
    </animated.div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will probably stick with the V8 as I'm more comfortable using component classes than component functions.

Comment: Ok. Also, It is better to wait until V9 is officially release and stable. Until then, we should use V8.

Comment: Wait so you're telling me that I can't use react-spring with custom component anymore? renderprops is all that I could use because I can't use animated on my components since it's limited to div

Answer (score 1):

It could be that onMouseLeave is being triggered on the first div just after onMouseEnter because it is unmounted, hence causing it to appear as if nothing is happening?

Wouldn't you just want onMouseEnter on the first one and onMouseLeave only on the second rather than both on each?

Comment: Failing that, what version of react-spring are you using? Looks like you need to import Spring from 'react-spring/renderprops', there's mention in the docks of V9 which unifies the api under one module but it isn't released yet?

Comment: You're right, it is unnecessary to be there but the hover text is appearing/dissappearing accordingly to the mouse enter/left therefor the event works right, but I removed it as it is useless. But the problem still persists. Also when I try to import spring/renderprops it gets me an error that no file like that exists. is there an npm install command for that ?

Comment: Could be because you're using version 9 which doesnt have the /renderprops anymore, check your package.json for the version? If you look here https://www.react-spring.io/log it's explained that version 9 may have breaking changes, could see if it works with version 8?

Comment: Yes, I'm using version 9. I will try version 8 and I will let you know.

Comment: Yes it was because of that version. With version 8 it works just perfect. Can't belive that I lost almost 3 hours figuring out why it's not working and it was because of the broken version 9. Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem :) we've all been there, don't sweat it, keep going!